# Pasting an array from another workbook into active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

**Scenario:** I am trying to open a workbook, get the data from it into an array, close it, and then past it to a selected worksheet of my active workbook.

**Problem:** I already tried looping and resizing directly (from what I saw form other posts and around the web, those seem to be the better solutions), but I still get the same error:

> Application defined or object defined error.

**Code:**

```
Sub BT_CA_ADJ()

Dim wbpath,  bidp_name As String
Dim wb, tabb As Workbook

Dim inpb As Variant

wbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


b_name = wb.Sheets("Instructions").Cells(4, 3)


Set tabb = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\" & b_name)

    inpb = tabb.Sheets(1).UsedRange


tabb.Close True


For i = 1 To UBound(inpb, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(inpb, 2)
        wb.Sheets("B").Cells(i + 2, j + 2).Value = inpb(i, j)

    Next j
Next i

' I also tried:
wb.Worksheets("B").[A1].Resize(UBound(inpb, 1), UBound(inpb, 2)) = inpb
```

Both result in the same error.

**Question:** Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the line of the error?

Comment: Just tried your code, just ran without any errors

Comment: @Magnetron on the 'wb.Sheets("B").Cells(i + 2, j + 2).Value = inpb(i, j)'

Comment: You can also copy the whole array into your workbook like this `wb.Sheets("B").Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(Ubound(inpb,1),Ubound(inpb,2)) = inpb`

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, it was totally my fault. there was a formula on the first cell of my original array. Can someone explain why that yields and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous imprecisions in your code which I have corrected in the code below.

```
Sub BT_CA_ADJ()

    Dim wbpath As String, bidp_name As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, tabb As Workbook
    Dim inpb As Variant

    wbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path

'    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    bidp_name = wb.Sheets("Instructions").Cells(4, 3).Value

    Set tabb = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\" & bidp_name)
    inpb = tabb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
    tabb.Close False

'    For i = 1 To UBound(inpb, 1)
'        For j = 1 To UBound(inpb, 2)
'            wb.Sheets("B").Cells(i + 2, j + 2).Value = inpb(i, j)
'
'        Next j
'    Next i

' I also tried:
    wb.Worksheets("B").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(inpb, 1), UBound(inpb, 2)) = inpb
End Sub
```

There were three principal errors. One is that you didn't specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet. Therefore you were able to use undeclared variables with unpredictable effect.
Two, any variable not declared as something else is presumed to be a variant. For example, `Dim wb, tabb As Workbook` does not declare `wb` as a workbook.
Three don't confuse ranges with the ranges' values. `Value` is the default property. Most of the time you can omit it to no ill effect other than confusing yourself. However, a variant can be either - the value or the range. Therefore, if you don't specify which one you mean you must live (or die) with Excel's best guess, even if that guess results in an error.
Having corrected the obvious faults doesn't mean that the code now works. It might. I haven't been able to test. However, please bear in mind that the file name you pick up from `Cells(4, 3)` must include the file name extension.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing you are declaring your `wb` variable as a `Variant` type and not a `Workbook` type.  If you want to string declarations together in the same line you have to do it like this:

`Dim wb as Workbook, tabb as Workbook`

Otherwise VBA auto assigns the undeclared variable as a `Variant` type which doesn't know how to handle a range of objects like the `Workbook` type does.

The same goes for your other `string` declarations, but the `Variant` type does know how to handle the `string` type so you won't get any errors from it, but it allocates a little more memory, because `Variant` types have to account for several different types rather than one specific type.

Comment: It would also help him if he used `Dim inpb() as Variant` and when assigning a value to it used the `.value` method. I think the `.value` bit is the main reason this is failing